# Read only one LookAt from kml

Tags: jquery, xml, kml, google-earth

I have a problem when i read a kml with jquery.I would read the field “lookAt only once.

Here a piece of code:

```
       ...
       $(xml).find( "LookAt" ).each(function(){


        if(!indicador_lookAt){

            var latitude = parseFloat(xml.find( "LookAt" ).find( "latitude" ).text());
            var longitude = parseFloat(xml.find( "LookAt" ).find( "longitude" ).text());
            var range = parseFloat(xml.find( "LookAt" ).find( "range" ).text());
            var tilt = parseFloat(xml.find( "LookAt" ).find( "tilt" ).text());
            var heading = parseFloat(xml.find( "LookAt" ).find( "heading" ).text());

            la = ge.createLookAt('');
            //la.set(latitude, longitude, 2500, ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE,heading, tilt, range);             
            la.setLatitude(latitude);
            la.setLongitude(longitude);
            la.setRange(range);
            la.setTilt(tilt);
            la.setHeading(heading);
            ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);
            indicador_lookAt=true;

            alert("latitud:  "+latitude+"  longitud:  "+longitude+"   zoom:  "+range+"   tilt:  "+tilt+"   heading:  "+heading);

        }

    });
...
```

And the piece of xml:

```
...
<gx:FlyTo>
    <gx:duration>2</gx:duration>
    <LookAt>
    <longitude>-4.836878478527069</longitude>
    <latitude>43.25472478453825</latitude>
    <altitude>0</altitude>
    <heading>263.4539184570312</heading>
    <tilt>60</tilt>
    <range>1500</range>
    </LookAt>
</gx:FlyTo>
<gx:FlyTo>
<gx:duration>10</gx:duration>
<gx:flyToMode>smooth</gx:flyToMode>
    <LookAt>
        <longitude>-4.873445226124237</longitude>
        <latitude>43.25166276236303</latitude>
        <altitude>0</altitude>
        <heading>251.5333862304688</heading>
        <tilt>60</tilt>
        <range>1500</range>
    </LookAt>
</gx:FlyTo>
…
```

All the variables content the sum of the above, for example “range” contents “15001500..”. Only need this variable content “1500”, how can I read only one "lookAt" from the kml?

Here an image capture

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the:

```
$(xml).find( "LookAt" ).each(function(){
```

only execute your code on the one you want.

Comment: I do that but the problem is at the range and tilt. These variables content the sum of all, i don`t know why. For example Latitude and longitude are OK.

Comment: Its so long and too many files. I thing I've found the problem. When a kml have got a tour tag (include too many lookAt) the function fail and the range is not well calculated.